# In PHP, when I use fwrite, I don't get the correct character set

Tags: php, file, encoding

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
  header("Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=UTF-8");

  $fName = "demo.txt";
  $str   = "óé";
  fid   = fopen($fName, 'wb') or die("can't open file"); // Open file

  fwrite($fid, $str); // Write to file
  fclose($fid);         // Close file
?>
```

To the screen, the output is:

```
óéü
```

When I open the file I get:

```
√≥√©√º
```

I am trying to save large amounts of data using fwrite, but the characters are not encoding correctly at the point of file save.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try [this suggestion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php#73764)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. It turns out that the VIEWER was the issue. I have a few text editors, and, depending on which one I used, I would get the UTF-8 character set or NOT! I wound up using Coda for everything and Have not had any other issues.

Answer (score 4):

`fwrite` stores strings binary. It does not do any charset conversion.
It's more likely that your PHP script is in a wrong charset, and thus the original `"óéü"` string. Show us the `bin2hex($str)` and `bin2hex(file_get_contents('demo.txt'))` if you can't debug it yourself.

There are some generic options to solve such problems:

- Using `utf8_encode($str)` before saving.
- Writing the UTF-8 BOM into the output file first `fwrite($f, "\xEF\xBB\xBF")`
- correct conversion with `iconv()`
- or adapting the php script itself with `recode L1..UTF8 script.php`

Answer (score 2):

what program are you using to "open" the file? that program could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, insert the utf_encode inside the fwrite, like this:

```
<?php

$fName = "demo.txt";
$str   = "óé";
fid   = fopen($fName, 'wb') or die("can't open file"); // Open file

fwrite($fid, utf_encode($str)); // Write to file
fclose($fid);         // Close file
?>
```

Next, remember to save your PHP script with `UTF-8 without BOM` encoding. Use any advanced code editor like Notepad++ to do this.