# Error with accents in Portuguese on a html page

Tags: php, html, powershell, dojo

I have a big problem with the accent in Portuguese on my little site. 
a Html page, which has the following fields:

```
Name input type="text";

Date of departure input type="text" with a Dojo calendar; 

Cancel Phone Number: Yes / No input type="radio"; 

Cancel the data plate: Yes / No input type="radio"; 

Other: textarea.
```

I get the values ​​of all fields in PHP, the data displayed in the php file are correct when echo is performed. the problem is when I create a `file.txt`, has also experienced a `.html` file but it does not convert the accents.

So when I send the file in a powershell script, when the email is received appears without accents, more properly the letters with accents not appear, see question marks (?)

--> my php variables <--

```
$ name = $ _POST   ['name']; 
$ date = $ _POST ['fromDate_out']; 
$ tele = $ _POST ['phone']; 
$ board = $ _POST ['board']; 
$ other = $ _POST ['other']; 
$ OriginalDate = $ date; 
$ Newdate = date ("d-m-Y", strtotime ($ OriginalDate));
```

--> creating the file im .txt and .html <--

```
$ fp = fopen (" SaidaColaborador . html", "w +"); 
$ write = fwrite ($ fp, "
< ! DOCTYPE html > 
< html > 
< body > 
  < head > 
   </ head> 
Name: ------------------------------------- $ name 
< br > Date: --------------------------------- $ Newdate 
< br > Cancel  number: - $ tele 
< br > Cancel  data plate: -------------- $ plate 
< br > Other: -------------------------------- $ other 
< / body > 
< / html > 
" ) ; 

fclose ( $ fp ); 


/ * 
$ fp = fopen ( " SaidaColaborador . txt " , " w + " ); 
$ write = fwrite ($ fp, "
Name: ------------------------------------- $ name 
<br> Date: --------------------------------- $ Newdate 
<br>Cancel number: -- $ tele 
<br>Cancel data plate: -------------- $ plate 
<br> Other: -------------------------------- $ other 
");

fclose ($ fp); 
* /
```

--> at last my powershell script <--

```
$ smtpServer = "my server" 
$ smtpTo = "receiver"
$ smtpTo2 = "receiver2"
$ smtpTo3 = "receiver3"
$ smtpFrom = "sender" 
$ messageSubject = "Saida_Colaborador"  

$ body = "<b> </b> <br>" 

$ file = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\SaidaColaboradorBCK03\FormColaboradorSaida\SaidaColaborador.html or .txt'
$ body + = Get - Content $ file 
send-MailMessage  -SmtpServer  $ smtpServer -To $ smtpTo3   -From $ smtpFrom  -Subject 
$ messageSubject   -Body  $ body  -BodyAsHtml  -Priority high
```

--> and i expect to do something like this <--

Nome : Diogo á é í ó ú â ê î ô û õ ã ç

Data : 01-05-2014

Cancelar número de telefone : Não

Cancelar placa de dados : Não

Outros : olá, á, pé, mão

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883035/in-php-when-i-use-fwrite-i-dont-get-the-correct-character-set - the answer may be there

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the encoding using the `utf8_encode` function, check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: I use a file, not a single string. it's possible to encode the .txt or .html file and send it?

Comment: Are you writing text to the .txt file? If so, the text needs to be encoded.

Comment: yes i write it on a txt file, and then I send the contents of the txt file in the body of the powershell script ($ body + = Get - Content $ file )